# Calculating statistical significance across differing metrics in A/B testing

Tags: ab-test

First up, apologies that this probably a dumb question.

I am switching careers and just getting started in trying to understand statistical significance in A/B testing. I've come into issues quickly in identifying the right statistical test.

I am trying to calculate statistical significance across a variety of KPIs within an A/B test for a mobile game (with an 80:20 control:experiment sampling ratio), but am struggling to identify which tests fit which KPIs.

For instance: comparing ARPU (*average revenue per user*) seems to require a different method to comparing *average revenue per user per game*. But I'm not successfully grasping the difference and why (binomial vs non-binomial? parametric vs non-parametric?).

I'm ultimately seeking some guidance on which tests would be appropriate for these KPIs, or guidance as to how I could determine which tests would be appropriate. For each of the below I have already gathered metrics but now want to validate the significance of the results.

1. **active days per user**
2. **active days per user out of possible days**
3. **games played per user**
4. **games played per user per active day**
5. **average revenue per user**
6. **average revenue per paying user**
7. **average revenue per daily active user**
8. **average revenue per game played**
9. **paid conversion rate** (chi squared?)
10. **average days from install to paid conversion**
11. **D1 retention rate, D3 retention rate, D7 retention rate, D14 retention rate**

Any help, big or small, would be incredibly valuable. Thank you.